# why a list of tuple which are colors can't be assigned to image array

Tags: image-processing, colors, slice, grayscale, color-coding

i want to apply different colors to my grayscale image which i want to change in pseducolor but the problem is that, when i create color map generally then when i apply it to the color_coded_img which is created in begin with zeros it show me an error which is ; ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (3,) + inhomogeneous part. i don't know how to resolve it,

`import cv2
import numpy as np
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
gray_img = cv2.imread('/content/drive/MyDrive/DIP3E_CH06_Original_Images/DIP3E_Original_Images_CH06/Fig0620(a)(picker_phantom).tif')
cv2_imshow(gray_img)

def slicing_gray_img_coloring(img,slic_nums):
interval_size = img // slic_nums

colors = [(0,0,i*interval_size) for i in range(slic_nums)]

color_coded_img = np.zeros((img.shape[0],img.shape[1],3), dtype=np.uint8)
for i in range(slic_nums):
lower_bound= i* interval_size

## upper_bound = (i + 1) * interval_size if (i + 1) * interval_size <= 255 else 255

```
upper_bound = np.clip((i + 1) * interval_size, 0, 255)

mask =cv2.inRange(img,lower_bound,upper_bound)
color_coded_img[np.where(mask > 0)] = colors[i]
```

return color_coded_img

num_intervals = 8
colored_coded_img= slicing_gray_img_coloring(gray_img,num_intervals)
cv2_imshow(colored_coded_img)
`
i tried this and i want to change my grayscale image to pseduocolor image by color coding